# Digest Auth using axios

Tags: node.js, axios

Has anyone performed 'digest auth' using the axios modules in nodejs? Unable to find the right configuration options to be set for the peforming the authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Don't seem to be support for digest
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/686

But there's another package
https://github.com/rearn/axios-digest

I haven't tried it though, and cant understans if it only support encrypted digestfile (not regular digest)

Answer (score 1):

I have used https://axios-digest-auth.mhoc.co/.

The example works for me.

```
import AxiosDigestAuth from '@mhoc/axios-digest-auth';

const digestAuth = new AxiosDigestAuth({
  username: process.env.MY_DIGEST_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.MY_DIGEST_PASSWORD,
});

const MakeARequest = async () => {
  const response = await digestAuth.request({
    headers: { Accept: "application/json" },
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups",
  });
}
```